# How do I test a function with gets.chomp in it?

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, shell, testing

I have a simple function using gets.chomp like this:

```
def welcome_user
   puts "Welcome! What would you like to do?"
   action = gets.chomp
end
```

I'd like to test it using `ruby`'s built in `TestCase` suite like this:

```
class ViewTest < Test::Unit::TestCase
   def test_welcome
      welcome_user      
   end 
end
```

The problem is, when I run that test, the `gets.chomp` stops the test because it needs the user to enter in something. Is there a way I can simulate user inputs using just `ruby`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You first separate the 2 concerns of the method:

```
def get_action
  gets.chomp
end

def welcome_user
  puts "Welcome to Jamaica and have a nice day!"
  action = get_action
  return "Required action was #{action}."
end
```

And then you test the second one separately.

```
require 'minitest/spec'
require 'minitest/autorun'

describe "Welcoming users" do
  before do
    def get_action; "test string" end
  end

  it "should work" do
    welcome_user.must_equal "Required action was test string."
  end
end
```

As for the first one, you can

1. Test it by hand and rely that it won't break (recommended approach, TDD is not a religion).
2. Get the subverted version of the shell in question and make it imitate the user, and compare
   whether `get_action` indeed gets what the user types.

While this is a practical answer to your problem, I do not know how to do 2., I only know how to imitate the user behind the browser (`watir-webdriver`) and not behind the shell session.

Answer (score 13):

You could create a [pipe](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/IO.html#method-c-pipe) and assign its "read end" to `$stdin`. Writing to the pipe's "write end" then simulates user input.

Here's an example with a little helper method `with_stdin` for setting up the pipe:

```
require 'test/unit'

class View
  def read_user_input
    gets.chomp
  end
end

class ViewTest < Test::Unit::TestCase
  def test_read_user_input
    with_stdin do |user|
      user.puts "user input"
      assert_equal(View.new.read_user_input, "user input")
    end
  end

  def with_stdin
    stdin = $stdin             # remember $stdin
    $stdin, write = IO.pipe    # create pipe assigning its "read end" to $stdin
    yield write                # pass pipe's "write end" to block
  ensure
    write.close                # close pipe
    $stdin = stdin             # restore $stdin
  end
end
```

Comment: Thnaks for that `IO.pipe`, you taught me something there.

Answer (score 3):

You could inject the IO dependency.  `gets` reads from `STDIN`, which is class `IO`.  If you inject another `IO` object into your class, you can use `StringIO` in your tests.  Something like this:

```
class Whatever
  attr_reader :action

  def initialize(input_stream, output_stream)
    @input_stream = input_stream
    @output_stream = output_stream
  end

  def welcome_user
    @output_stream.puts "Welcome! What would you like to do?"
    @action = get_input
  end

private

  def get_input
    @input_stream.gets.chomp
  end

end
```

Tests:

```
require 'test/unit'
require 'stringio'
require 'whatever'

class WhateverTest < Test::Unit::TestCase
  def test_welcome_user
    input = StringIO.new("something\n")
    output = StringIO.new
    whatever = Whatever.new(input, output)

    whatever.welcome_user

    assert_equal "Welcome! What would you like to do?\n", output.string
    assert_equal "something", whatever.action
  end
end
```

This allows your class to interact with any IO stream (TTY, file, network, etc.).

To use it on the console in production code, pass in `STDIN` and `STDOUT`:

```
require 'whatever'

whatever = Whatever.new STDIN, STDOUT
whatever.welcome_user

puts "Your action was #{whatever.action}"
```