# end to end test of a ruby console app

Tags: ruby

I have a ruby console app that you run with an argument, then once running outputs some text to the screen, asks for some more user input and then outputs some more text to the screen.  I want to do an end to end test on this app and I don't know how.  If I were writing an end to end test for an REST API, I would just hit the public endpoint, follow the links and then have an expect statement on the output.  Easy.  But on a console app I have no idea how to do the same thing.  Are there any gems for stepping through a console app in the context of a test?  I've been looking all day but can't find anything.

ANY help appreciated.

Comment: This could help: [How do I test a function with gets.chomp in it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16948645/how-do-i-test-a-function-with-gets-chomp-in-it)

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by [this gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/capture_stdout) which has a fairly simple [implementation](https://github.com/svenfuchs/capture_stdout/blob/master/lib/capture_stdout.rb), I wrote a method which captures console input & output and can, therefore, be used in tests:

```
require 'stringio'

module Kernel
  def emulate_console(console_input)
    $stdin = StringIO.new(console_input)
    out = StringIO.new
    $stdout = out
    yield
    return out
  ensure
    $stdout = STDOUT
    $stdin = STDIN
  end
end
```

This method captures console output, and also provides as input the string value which you specify in the `console_input` parameter.

#### Basic usage

Here's a simple usage of the `emulate_console` method:

```
out = emulate_console("abc\n") do
  input = gets.chomp
  puts "You entered: #{input}!"
end
```

The return value `out` is a [`StringIO`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/stringio/rdoc/StringIO.html) object. To access its value, use the [`#string` method](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/stringio/rdoc/StringIO.html#method-i-string):

```
out.string
=> "You entered: abc!\n"
```

Note that the input contains a newline character (`\n`) to simulate pressing the <kbd>ENTER</kbd> key.

#### Testing

Now, let's assume that you want to test this method, that uses both stdin and stdout:

```
def console_add_numbers
  x = Integer(gets)
  y = Integer(gets)
  puts x + y
end
```

The following RSpec test tests the happy path of this code:

```
require 'rspec/autorun'

RSpec.describe '#console_add_numbers' do
  it 'computes correct result' do
    input = <<-EOS
2
3
EOS

    output = emulate_console(input) { console_add_numbers }

    expect(output.string.chomp).to eql '5'
  end
end
```