# rspec 3 error when user is prompted for input

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, rspec3

I have code that is requesting the user for input, such as:

```
class Foo
  def prompt_for_foobar
    puts "where is the foobar?"
    gets.chomp
  end
end
```

I would like to test that my application is asking "where is the foobar?". My test will pass upon commenting out 'gets.chomp'. but that is needed and the anything else I have tried has given me a Errno::ENOENT: error.

```
it "should prompt user" do
  console = Foo.new
  request = "where is the foobar?"
  expect { console.prompt_for_foobar }.to output(request).to_stdout
end
```

What is the best way to test this method?

Comment: Possible duplicate of this concept: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16948645/how-do-i-test-a-function-with-gets-chomp-in-it

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the best way to handle this, but you can send `puts` and `gets` to `STDOUT` and `STDIN`.

```
class Foo
  def prompt_for_foobar
    STDOUT.puts "where is the foobar?"
    STDIN.gets.chomp
  end
end
```

Then, test that `STDIN` receives that `puts` message with your desired object.

```
describe Foo do
  let(:foo) { Foo.new }

  before(:each) do
    allow(STDIN).to receive(:gets) { "user input" }
  end

  describe "#prompt_for_foobar" do
    it "prompts the user" do
      expect(STDOUT).to receive(:puts).with("where is the foobar?")

      foo.prompt_for_foobar
    end

    it "returns input from the user" do
      allow(STDOUT).to receive(:puts)

      expect(foo.prompt_for_foobar).to eq "user input"
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `gets` is a method that forces human interaction (at least in the context of RSpec, where stdin isn't connected to a pipe from another process), but the entire point of automated testing tools like RSpec are to be able to run tests without involving human interaction.

So, rather than relying directly on `gets` in your method, I recommend you rely on a collaborator object that implements a particular interface -- that way in the test environment you can provide an implementation of that interface that provides a response without human interaction, and in other environments it can use `gets` to provide a response.  The simplest collaborator interface here is probably a proc (they're perfect for this kind of thing!), so you could do the following:

```
class Foo
  def prompt_for_foobar(&responder)
    responder ||= lambda { gets }
    puts "where is the foobar?"
    responder.call.chomp
  end
end

RSpec.describe Foo do
  it 'prompts the user to respond' do
    expect { Foo.new.prompt_for_foobar { "" } }.to output(/where is the foobar/).to_stdout
  end

  it "returns the responder's response" do
    expect(Foo.new.prompt_for_foobar { "response" }).to eq("response")
  end
end
```

Notice that `prompt_for_foobar` no longer calls `gets` directly; instead it delegates the responsibility of getting a response to a `responder` collaborator.  By default, if no responder is provided, it uses `gets` as a default implementation of a responder.  In your test you can easily provide a responder that requires no human interaction simply by passing a block that returns a string.