# Basic introduction to Ruby Minitest

Tags: ruby, testing, minitest, assertion

I am using minitest for the first time and I am having trouble understanding how to write my first test method. Can anyone assist in helping me understand what I should be testing in the below Player method get_name?

```rb
class Player
  def get_name(player)
    puts `clear`
    center("#{player}, whats your name bro/ladybro?")
    @name = gets.chomp
    until @name =~ /\A[[:alnum:]]+\z/
      center("you can do a combination of alphanumeric characters")
      @name = gets.chomp
    end
  end
end
```

This is what I have in my test file, I was thinking I am just suppose to test the regex to make sure it takes alpha and numeric characters.

```rb
class TestPlayer < Minitest::Test
  def test_get_name
    describe "get_name" do
      it "should allow an input of alphanumeric characters" do
        assert_match(/\A[[:alnum:]]+\z/, "test_string123")
      end
    end
  end
end
```

but when I run the tests, nothing seems to happen, I would imagine I am suppose to have 1 assertion.

```
Run options: --seed 10135

# Running:

.

Finished in 0.001565s, 638.9776 runs/s, 0.0000 assertions/s.

1 runs, 0 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips
```

can anyone assist in demonstrating how I should write a test for this scenario? thanks.

Comment: Whats the method `center`?

Comment: @JikkuJose my bad, the method center is just a formatting thing, this is an excerpt form a basic terminal tic tac toe game, center is just suppose to center the text across a 178 character screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Minitest test may be described as follows (*Assertion* syntax):

1. Its just a simple Ruby file which has a class thats typically a subclass of `Minitest::Test`.
2. The method `setup` will be called at the first; you can define objects that you may require in every test. Eg: Consider assigning an instance of the `Player` object here in an instance variable in `setup` method so that you can use it elsewhere in the test class.
3. A test is defined inside a method that starts with the string: `test_`; any other method can be used to reduce duplication of code but it won't be considered part of tests.
4. Typically you should think about *testing* the return value of a method you want to test.
5. Testing a method with external input is [more convoluted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16950202/2602869), I would suggest to start with testing methods that have testable output.

Comment: thanks for the details, short and to the point, that clarifies things somewhat for me, Ill take another go at other functions that do not involve user input.