# Testing program that runs with user input from the console

Tags: ruby, minitest

I'm writing tests for a system that models an elevator. For example, I want to test that the elevator can change direction and that it can move to a specified floor.

I have the following methods:

```
def initialize
  @current_floor = 0
  @requested_floor = 0
end
def get_value
  gets.chomp
end
def arrival
  print "Enter floor number: "
  @requested_floor = get_value
  # only proceed if user entered an integer
  if validate_floor_number(@requested_floor)
    @requested_floor = @requested_floor.to_i
    move
  else
    arrival
  end
end
def move
  msg = ""
  @current_floor < @requested_floor ? msg = "Going Up!" : msg = "Going Down"
  puts msg
  @current_floor = @requested_floor
  next_move
end
def next_move
  puts "Do you want to go to another floor? Y/N"
  another_floor = (get_value).upcase
  another_floor == 'N' ? final_destination : arrival
end
```

I start the program by calling `Elevator.new.arrival`. To check that the elevator has changed directions, I need to store the value of `@current_floor` in a temporary variable then check it's value has changed after `move` has been called.

I am testing input from the console using an IO pipe thanks to the answers in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16948645/how-do-i-test-a-function-with-gets-chomp-in-it), but I'm not sure how to apply that knowledge to user interaction that's part of a method.

How can I simulate the program running from the start (`Elevator.new.arrival`) through the `move` method and *stop it there* so I can check the value of `@current_floor` - all of this without running the program itself and using the IO pipe to simulate user interaction?

I have a feeling that I might have gone about the design of the program in the wrong way. If anyone can even point me in the right direction towards solving this problem I'd appreciate it.

**Edit**

According to the suggestions from Wand Maker I've written a test as follows:

```
  describe "checks that the elevator can change directions" do
    before do
      moves = [3, 'Y', 5, 'Y', 2, 'Y', 7, 'N']
      def get_value; moves.next end
    end

    it "should stop on floor 7" do
      Elevator.new.arrival
      assert_equal(@current_floor, 7)
    end
  end
```

Unfortunately, when I run my test file, the program still runs and prompts for user input. Maybe I'm calling `arrival` incorrectly but I can't think of another way to do it.

Comment: Are you sure you have overwritten Elevator class' instance method `get_value` - May be you should open the class and overwrite it.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what you mean? I don't know another way of overriding the method from the test file other than what was suggested in that question you linked to (see edited answer).

Comment: I have updated my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As demonstrated in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16948786/794242), you can override `getvalue` to feed in the user input.

Here is complete code that works without actually using `gets`.  I had to add couple of missing methods -  `validate_floor_number` and `final_destination`:

```
require 'minitest/autorun'

class Elevator
  attr_accessor :current_floor

  def initialize
    @current_floor = 0
    @requested_floor = 0
    #@last_floor = false
  end

  def get_value
    gets.chomp
  end

  def validate_floor_number(v)
    v.to_i rescue false
  end

  def arrival
    print "Enter floor number: "
    @requested_floor = get_value

    # only proceed if user entered an integer
    if validate_floor_number(@requested_floor)
      @requested_floor = @requested_floor.to_i
      move
    else
      arrival
    end
  end

  def move
    msg = ""
    @current_floor < @requested_floor ? msg = "Going Up!" : msg = "Going Down"
    puts msg
    @current_floor = @requested_floor
    next_move
  end

  def final_destination 
    puts "Reached your floor"
  end

  def next_move
    puts "Do you want to go to another floor? Y/N"
    another_floor = (get_value).upcase
    another_floor == 'N' ? final_destination : arrival
  end

 end 

 describe "checks that the elevator can change directions" do
    before do
      class Elevator
          @@moves = [3, 'Y', 5, 'Y', 2, 'Y', 7, 'N'].each
          def get_value; @@moves.next end
      end
    end

    it "should stop on floor 7" do
      e = Elevator.new
      e.arrival
      assert_equal(e.current_floor, 7)
    end
 end
```

Output of above program:

```
Run options: --seed 2561

# Running:

Enter floor number: Going Up!
Do you want to go to another floor? Y/N
Enter floor number: Going Up!
Do you want to go to another floor? Y/N
Enter floor number: Going Down
Do you want to go to another floor? Y/N
Enter floor number: Going Up!
Do you want to go to another floor? Y/N
Reached your floor
.

Finished in 0.001334s, 749.4982 runs/s, 749.4982 assertions/s.

1 runs, 1 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips
[Finished in 0.3s]
```

Comment: I've tried implementing your suggestions (see updated question) but I think I'm still missing something? When I run my test file I'm still being prompted for user input.

Comment: Okay I have updated the answer based on your updated question.

Comment: Just wanna double check, do I need to override the arrival method as well in the test file? I'm getting the error: `undefined method 'arrival' for #<ElevatorTest::Elevator:0x000000021ae198>` - could this be a syntax error on my part?

Comment: I am not sure how you have organized your version of the code - but if you copy/paste the above code in a `.rb` file, it runs fine without any error

Comment: Yeah your code runs fine no problem but I have my tests in a separate file in the same folder. I'd really like to keep it this way for usability. Thanks so much for your help so far but I think there's just one last problem - @current_floor is still not being read. It's giving me another undefined method error even with the attr_accessor you've added. I've tried adding `@@current_floor = 0` (and also just a normal instance variable) to the overridden Elevator class in the test file but that doesn't help.

Comment: When accessing instance variable from outside the class, you need to use `object.instance_var_name` syntax to access instance variables - hope you are doing that instead of directly using `@current_floor.

Comment: I've added another attr_accessor to the overriden class in the test suite (is this wrong?) but the test fails because e.current_floor is returning `nil` so I think I have to completely override the arrival, move, and next_move methods in the test_suite? Am I wrong in thinking this or is that the right path to go on.

Comment: I dont think so many methods need to be overridden for testability.  Your code may have some flaws.   I hope you will figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

<sup>This answers this part of your question: *How can I simulate the program running from the start (Elevator.new.arrival) through the move method **and stop it there so I can check the value of @current_floor?***</sup>

1. Install byebug: `gem install byebug`
2. Require it in your file: `require 'byebug'`
3. Add `byebug` command where you want to stop your program, for example at start of `move` (see code at the end of the post)
4. You are dropped in a shell and can examine everything, for example `@current_floor` by typing it out, or the instance by using `self`
5. If you want to continue, hit `CTRL+D` and the program will continue (with any modification you might have done)

That should help you debugging it.

```
def move
  byebug # <-- program will stop here
  msg = ""
  @current_floor < @requested_floor ? msg = "Going Up!" : msg = "Going Down"
  puts msg
  @current_floor = @requested_floor
  next_move
end
```