# Trouble getting tests to run properly

Tags: ruby, minitest

I've been trying to test a program that simulates an elevator for two days now with little success. Here's my elevator class, the program is still a work in progress and I've also commented out some methods that might not be essential to the test I'm having trouble with. I'll gladly show more code if you think it's needed

```
class Elevator
  attr_accessor :current_floor

  GROUND = 0
  TOP = 15

  def initialize
    @floors = []                  # list of floors to travel to
    @pending = []                 # store floors not in direction of travel
    @current_floor = GROUND
    @going_up = true              # cannot travel downward from ground floor
    @going_down = false
  end

  def get_input
    gets.chomp
  end

  def run
    enter_floors
    sort_floors
    move_to_floor
  end

  def enter_floors
    # prompts the user for input and calls check_floor_numbers
  end

  def check_floor_numbers floors
    # calls validate_floors to ensure user entered '2' instead of 'two'
    # if proper floor numbers have been entered this method adds the number
    # to @floors array other wise it calls floor_error_message
  end

  def floor_error_message
    puts "Please enter numbers only."
    enter_floors
  end

  def sort_floors
    # if we are on the ground floor this method sorts @floors in ascending order
    # if we are on the top floor it sorts @floors in descending order
    # else it calls check_direction_of_travel
  end

  def move_to_floor
    floor = @floors[0]

    if @current_floor == floor
      puts "You are already on floor #{floor}"
    else
      print_direction
      (@current_floor..floor).each { |floor| puts "...#{floor}" }
      @current_floor = floor            # update current_floor
      @floors.delete_at(0)              # remove floor from list
    end

    check_for_more_passengers
  end

  def check_for_more_passengers
    puts "Are there any more passengers? (Y/N)"
    answer = (get_input).upcase

    answer == 'Y' ? run : check_next_move
  end

  def check_next_move
    if @floors.empty? && @pending.empty?
      end_ride
    else
      move_to_floor
    end
  end

  def check_direction_of_travel
    # not implemented - add floor to appropriate array depending on dir
    # of travel
  end

  def end_ride
    puts "\n\nEND."
  end

  def print_direction
    msg = " "
    @going_up ? msg = "Going Up!" : msg = "Going Down!"
    puts msg
  end
end
```

I'm trying to test that the elevator can move to a specific floor. At first I was having trouble testing input from the console without running the program itself. I [asked a question about this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33854700/testing-program-that-runs-with-user-input-from-the-console) and was referred to [this answer in a different question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16948645/how-do-i-test-a-function-with-gets-chomp-in-it/16948786#16948786). The answer in question extract `gets.chomp` to a separate method then overrides the method in the tests. I ended up with something like this:

```
  describe "it can move to a floor" do
    before do
        @@moves = ["2", "N"]
        def get_input; @@moves.next end
    end

    it "should move to floor 2" do
      e = Elevator.new
      e.run
      assert_equal(e.current_floor, 2)
    end
  end
```

**Problem:**  `get_input` was not properly overidden and running the test suit prompted the user for input so it was suggested that I [open the Elevator class in the test itself](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33854943/2733137) to ensure that the method was properly overridden. Attempting to do so eventually led to a test like this:

```
  describe "it can move to a floor" do
    before do
      class Elevator
        attr_accessor :current_floor
        @@moves = ["2", "N"]
        def get_input; @@moves.next end
        def run; end
      end
    end

    it "should move to floor 2" do
      e = Elevator.new
      e.run
      assert_equal(e.current_floor, 2)
    end
  end
```

I had to override `run` and add an attr_accessor for `current_floor` because I was getting method missing errors.

**Problem:** This test gives the following error:

> 1) Failure: it can move to a floor#test_0001_should move to floor 2
>   [elevator_test.rb:24]: Expected: nil   Actual: 2

I've tried to tidy up the Elevator class as much as possible and keep the methods as simple as I could given the parameters of the program.

Can anyone point me in the right direction towards getting this solved, with maybe pseudocode examples (if possible) to demonstrate how I should approach this problem if the answer is to refactor.

Please bear in mind that I'd also like to implement other tests like checking that the elevator class can maintain a list of floors, or that it can change direction, in the future when you answer.

Comment: `@floors` is an empty array and your code uses `@floors[0]` which happens to be nil.  Your code as shown above gives error  `ArgumentError: bad value for range`

Comment: The elevator class runs fine for me. Would you like me to put the entire uncommented class up on github?

Comment: If its okay with you, you can share it - and put a link of that in the question above.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/sheekap/730088ddef85511dbd3e (@floors is populated in the check_floor_number method)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your test class `ElevatorTest` is redefining the `Elevator` to override method `get_input`, but it is not opening the class `Elevator` defined in `elevator.rb`, but instead it is sort of creating a new class `Elevator` which happens to be defined inside the class `ElevatorTest`.   Remember every class is also a module, so now you have a new class `ElevatorTest::Elevator`.

To fix this issue, I have made some changes to `elevator_test.rb` which is shown below.

```
gem 'minitest', '>= 5.0.0'
require 'minitest/spec'
require 'minitest/autorun'
require_relative 'elevator'

class Elevator
    @@moves = ["2", "N"].each
    def get_input; @@moves.next end
end

class ElevatorTest < MiniTest::Test
  def test_working
    assert_equal(1, 1)
  end

  describe "it can move to a floor" do
    before do
    end

    it "should move to floor 2" do
      e = Elevator.new
      e.run
      assert_equal(e.current_floor, 2)
    end
  end
end
```

Also, please remember to use `.each` while defining `@@moves` - it returns an enumerator.  We can call `.next` only on an enumerator

Comment: Thank you! That explanation helps a lot and the tests are passing now :)